# How's the Major number allocated for platform device driver?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, device-driver, spi

I wonder how the major number is allocated for platform device driver. 
For example, in the [driver code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c?v=3.4), I don't see any of the function calls like

```
alloc_chrdev_region()
```

or

```
register_chrdev_region()
```

Somebody, please make me understand this.
Thank you.

Comment: A general question: why would you think that MCSPI controller needs a char device major? It has nothing to do with user visible char devices.

Comment: It is a convention. See also `udev`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel creates a great deal of devices attached to various virtual buses (which may or may not represent a physical one). Only some of those devices can be meaningfully accessed directly from user space. And only a subset of those relies on "device node" interface to do so (as ample other options exist in modern kernels). If this particular interface is not used by a driver, then there's no need whatsoever to allocate device node numbers.

Inside the kernel devices are located by their affiliation to particular buses (using internal device names and bus ids). For example, `mcspi` driver registers as "device" on "platform bus" and as "bus master" on "spi bus". Upon seeing that bus master had registered, spi subsystem will trigger a "bus rescan" on a newly connected bus.

The `spidev` driver is rigged in such a way as to always "match" an imaginary device present on every spi bus, so it will get instantiated for every "bus master" registration. It will create the user space device node which can be used for direct communication with its "bus master" (spi bus controller, `mcspi` in this particular case).

Answer (score 0):

Controller doesn't need to be exposed. Hence, no device nos.

On the other hand, `SPI` devices do require a MAJOR?MINOR no defined in [spidev.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spidev.c#L671), here it is registering the device. And on the [top](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spidev.c#L56) of the same file, there's a macro for the major no defined as:

> 56   #define SPIDEV_MAJOR                    153     /* assigned */
>    57   #define N_SPI_MINORS                    32      /* ... up to 256 */

Comment: How is this controller driver different from char driver?

Comment: Controller is controller, `spidev` is entirely different driver which you can use to connect to the controller from user space.

Comment: @brokenfoot Your answer is basically wrong. `mcspi` is a controller driver on its own and is not directly linked to `spidev`.

Comment: @oakad: can you please elaborate on the difference between spidev driver and mcspi controller driver. Please provide supporting links.

Comment: See my answer. As for supporting links - check out "Linux Device Drivers" book, chapter 14 of 3rd edition (but better look for newer editions).